# No display from glDrawElements

Tags: c++, opengl

When I use glDrawArrays I get a triangle in the middle of my screen, as expected.
But when I try to use glDrawElements nothing comes up at all.

I have tried all sorts of things like reordering the gl calls, moving the attribute pointers, and even hard coding verts and index appears to do nothing as shown in my code.

This code runs once:

```
// Initialise GLFW
if( !glfwInit() )
{
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        //return -1;
}

glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE); //We don't want the old OpenGL

// Open a window and create its OpenGL context
if( !glfwOpenWindow( mApplication->getWindowWidth(), mApplication->getWindowHeight(), 0,0,0,0, 32,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
{
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        //return -1;
}

// Initialize GLEW
glewExperimental=true; // Needed in core profile
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
{
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        //return -1;
}

glfwSetWindowTitle( "Hello World" );
glViewport( 0, 0, mApplication->getWindowWidth(), mApplication->getWindowHeight());
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f); // colour to use when clearing
```

This runs every step:

```
float verts[] = {
        -0.5f,  0.0f,   0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.0f,   0.0f,
         0.0f,  0.5f,   0.0f,
};

unsigned int index[] = {
        1, 2, 3,
};

glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

// VAO
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

// VBO
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO );
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts) * sizeof(float), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

// IBO
glGenBuffers(1, &IBO );
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(index) * sizeof(unsigned int), index, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // this works
//glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &index); // this doesnt

glfwSwapBuffers();
```

This is a very cut down version of what I am trying to achieve but the problem is exactly the same.

Comment: So you create your VAO/VBOs every time you draw? That is not the way to do it. Create once.. then draw.

Comment: @legends2k i have read that, and it still looks like my code should run.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &index); // this
>   doesn't work

Of course it doesn't. You are storing your indices in a buffer object. In the same way the last pointer argument to `glVertexAttribPointer` is interpreted as an offset into the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` (if one is bound), the last pointer argument to `glDrawElements` is interpreted as an offset into the buffer currently bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. You already properly store your indices into that, so you have to tell `` `glDrawElements `` that the indices start at offset 0 of this buffer, like you did with `glVertexAttribPointer`:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

**EDIT:** And like *bwroga* points out in his answer, you should start your indices with `0` instead of `1`.

**EDIT:** And you also pass the wrong sizes into `glBufferData`. You use `sizeof(verts) * sizeof(floats)` (and likewise for `index`), but `verts` is an array and the `sizeof` an array already is the size of the whole thing in bytes and not just the number of elements, so it should rather just be `sizeof(verts)`, otherwise the `glBufferData` will try to read data beyond the actual array size which is undefined behaviour (and in your case unfortunately seems to work).

**EDIT:** And of course as *Grimmy* points out in his comment you shouldn't recreate your VAO and VBO each time you draw, that's initialization stuff. But this is more of a conceptual/optimization error (albeit a severe one) rather than an actual "non-working" error.

Comment: the nullptr thing was the key, thanks. the documentation for gl is pretty confusing at time, it reads as if you need to point to the memory location of the index list.

Comment: @Brae Because that was how `glDrawElements` (and `glVertexAttribPointer`) was used before VBOs came into play.

Comment: @Brae *"the nullptr thing was the key"* - But still don't ignore the other errors, they're equally severe.

Comment: `nullptr` Suggesting that you use that instead of 0 is probably a bad idea. It's supposed to be a byte offset; it's just *taken* as a pointer value. If you want to use a non-zero value, you now need to do a cast, which you should have been doing all along. It's best to give the example that's most easy to change later.

Comment: @NicolBolas It is still a pointer argument and if using an offset, that has to be specified as pointer anyway. Since `3` wouldn't work (as opposed to `static_cast<const char*>(nullptr)+3`, or `reinpterpret_cast<const void*>(3)`), I consider `0` counter-intuitive, too. Maybe `reinterpret_cast<const void*>(0)` would do, but I'd like to avoid that. But maybe it's a problem of viewpoint. `nullptr` doesn't hide the fact that it's first and foremost a pointer-typed argument, no matter how it's interpeted by the function.

Comment: "*I'd like to avoid that*" But you *can't* avoid that. Not everybody uses 0 as their offset, and it's best to show code that can easily be changed to accommodate different offsets. And that ridiculous "cast nullptr to a pointer and add to it" is a horrible idea. The value of a null pointer does not *have* to be zero.

Comment: @NicolBolas But neither is a `reinterpret_cast` from int to pointer a particularly good idea (especially on a system where `nullptr` is *not* 0), but that's OpenGL. Of course I cannot avoid that `reintepret_cast` (or an equally ulgy thing) when using non-zero offset, but using `reinterpret_cast<const void*>(0)` in place of `nullptr` just hurts. If anyone (or me) has to change that into a general offset some day, then he can do it himself. And I'd still say in this particular answer it demonstrates the fact better than such a `reinterpret_cast` construct (and a plain `0` is out of the question)

Comment: Thank you for this!

The OpenGL documentation states that the final argument in glDrawElements "Specifies a pointer to the location where the indices are stored.". Very misleading!

Comment: this answer saved my life; I'm using PyOpenGL and didn't realize that glDrawElements should accept a `ctypes.c_voidp(0)` as the last argument instead of a 0.

Answer (score 5):

I think this:

```
unsigned int index[] = {
    1, 2, 3,
};
```

should be this:

```
unsigned int index[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start your index at zero as others have pointed out.  But there is one other problem I see...

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &index);
```

should be...

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, index);
```

...as index is an array, it is already a pointer, no need for &.